# I am trying to make a profanity counter by myself for a discord bot without watching youtube tutorial. I got the following issue of bot not responding

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
import os
from List import Curse

#Running discord
client=discord.Client()

#Bot tells it is online
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

#To estabilish contact between users and the bot
  @client.event
  async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
      return

#checks whether the given word is a curse word or not
    if message.content.startswith(str(Curse)):
      await message.channel.send('Noo! stop speaking the lanuguage of the naughty nation!')

client.run("Discord TOKEN")
```

So, yeah, I have made a profanity counter which is supposed to check and respond, but it is not giving any response, neither error nor result

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that:

```
from List import Curse
```

Is importing a list of curse words, and then you are using the list like this:

```
if message.content.startswith(str(Curse)):
```

You are checking if your message content starts with your whole list as a string. i.e. '["curse1","curse2","curse3"]'.

You need to check if the message starts with ANY of the values in the list.

```
if any(message.content.startswith(curse) for curse in Curse):
```

This will send your message if any of the messages start with one of the curse words in the list.

I would suggest an improvement (as you are only currently checking the start of the message).

```
if any(curse in message.content for curse in Curse):
```

This will not only check the start of the message but the whole message.

You could go even further and ignore upper/lower case by doing this:

```
if any(curse.lower() in str(message.content).lower() for curse in Curse):
```

Comment: Holy shit man, I am new to coding and you are just awesome.

Comment: I have done what you told me, but for some reason, the bot is answering to all statements, i don't think I should send my curse list, but I think I have to now, should I send it?